# To Solve a linear PDE of first order 2

Tags: partial-differential-equations

To Solve:
$\displaystyle y^2\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}-xy\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}=x(z-2y)$

My attempt:

Forming the subsidiary equations: $\displaystyle \frac{dx}{y^2}=\frac{dy}{-xy}=\frac{dz}{x(z-2y)}$

$\displaystyle \frac{dx}{y^2}=\frac{dy}{-xy}$

$\displaystyle xdx=-ydy$

$\displaystyle x^2+y^2=C_1$

The given answer is: $\displaystyle x^2+y^2=f(y^2-yz)$

How did we get the second part ?

Comment: is $f$ a constant?

Comment: Its a function..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From
$$\frac{dx}{y^2}=\frac{dy}{-xy}=\frac{dz}{x(z-2y)}$$
We obtain:
$$\frac{dx}{y^2}=\frac{dy}{-xy} \implies xdx+ydy=0 \implies d(x^2+y^2)=0......(1)$$

$$\frac{dy}{-xy}=\frac{dz}{x(z-2y)} \implies (z-2y)dy=-ydz \implies d(y^2-yz)=0......(2)$$

So the solutions to the original equation are:

$$x^2+y^2=f(y^2-yz)......(3)$$
or
$$g(x^2+y^2)=y^2-yz......(4)$$

Because if we take $d$ operation on the first solution we have:

$$0=d(x^2+y^2)=f'(y^2-yz)d(y^2-yz)=0$$

Similarly:

$$0=g'(x^2+y^2) d(x^2+y^2)=d(y^2-yz)=0$$

Comment: Hi Mike .. Could you please help me with https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/840741/form-a-pde-by-eliminating-the-arbitrary-function