# Solving $\displaystyle x(z-2y^2)\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}=\left(z-\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}\right)(z-y^2-2x^3)$.

Tags: partial-differential-equations

To Solve:
$$\displaystyle x(z-2y^2)\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}=\left(z-\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}\right)(z-y^2-2x^3)$$

Forming the subsidiary equations: $\displaystyle \frac{dx}{x(z-2y^2)}=\frac{dy}{yz-y^3-2x^3y}=\frac{dz}{z^2-y^2z-2x^3z}$

My Attempt: $\displaystyle \frac{dy}{y(z-y^2-2x^3)}=\frac{dz}{z(z-y^2-2x^3)}$

$\displaystyle \frac{dy}{y}=\frac{dz}{z}$

$\displaystyle \frac{y}{z}=C_1 ; d\left(\frac{y}{z}\right)=0$

I can't think of the second part .. Please help.

The given answer is: $\displaystyle f\left(\frac{y}{x},\frac{z}{x}-\frac{y}{x}+x^2\right)=0$

Comment: Please take a look at the solution of [this question] [1] and [this question][2]


  [1]: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/842325/to-solve-a-linear-pde-of-first-order-2/842338?noredirect=1#comment1737096_842338
  [2]: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/840741/form-a-pde-by-eliminating-the-arbitrary-function

Comment: I got $\displaystyle d\left(\frac{y}{z}\right)=0$ .. but answer requires $\displaystyle d\left(\frac{y}{x}\right)=0$ .. What's wrong here ?

Comment: I will take a look.

Answer (score 1):

Please take a look at the solution of [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/842325/to-solve-a-linear-pde-of-first-order-2/842338?noredirect=1#comment1737096_842338) and [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/840741/form-a-pde-by-eliminating-the-arbitrary-function)

The goal is to prove that
$$d\left(\frac{y}{x}\right)=0,d\left(\frac{z}{x}-\frac{y}{x}+x^2\right)=0$$

Comment: I got $\displaystyle d\left(\frac{y}{z}\right)=0$ .. but answer requires $\displaystyle d\left(\frac{y}{x}\right)=0$ .. What's wrong here ?